# Destiny 2 Digital Deluxe items

Tags: destiny-2

The Digital Deluxe version of Destiny 2 comes with a few in-game items, but I can't find them. There's nothing in the mail or inventory or any info about them showing up at all. I guess my characters are just not qualified yet.

> Legendary Sword
>   Legendary Player Emote
>   Cabal Empire Themed Emblem

What do I need to do/have in order to get them and where do I get them? Can I get the them for any character or just one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your character must complete the campaign before receiving these items and I'm almost sure they are delivered via the Postmaster.

You'll only get one of each item, as they're account bound. You can transfer them to different characters via the Vault.